# Mat stepper request param

Tags: angular, mat, stepper

Hello im using mat stepper..

What i want to achieve is:

get step number from request param and show second step like this: http://localhost:4200/matstepper?step=2

Pass and retrieve request param is no problem, but how can i show second or third step?

is this possible? thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the selectedIndex property on the stepper:

```
<mat-stepper [selectedIndex]="calculatedStepIndex">...</mat-stepper>
```

Comment: Thanks, and is it possible to start indexing steps from 1 not from 0?

Comment: No you have to manage that yourself.